# Split comma separated string with commas as decimal delimiter into numbers

Tags: r, split

I am writing to ask a simple question, but I have not been able to solve it. I want to separate a string in R, in which there are comma delimited decimal numbers, which also are comma separated. The only regularity that exists is that any number has only two decimal places, but sometimes the numbers are in parentheses.

**input:**

```
0,60,(0,50),0,71,1,28,1,77,1,60,1,87
```

**desired result:**

```
0.60, (0.50), 0.71, 1.28, 1.77, 1.60, 1.87
```

Comment: Does this solve your problem? `x="0,60,(0,50),0,71,1,28,1,77,1,60,1,87"`; `gsub(",(\\d{2})", ".\\1", x)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way:

```r
input <- '0,60,(0,50),0,71,1,28,1,77,1,60,1,87'

spl <- strsplit(input, ',')[[1]]
even <- !(seq_along(spl) %% 2)
paste0(spl[!even], '.', spl[even])
# [1] "0.60"   "(0.50)" "0.71"   "1.28"   "1.77"   "1.60"   "1.87"
```

Splits `input` in `','` and reconcatenates subsequent odd and even parts with `'.'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try look-aheads.

```
el((strsplit(x, ',(?=\\()|,(?=\\d{1},)', perl=TRUE)))
# [1] "0,60"   "(0,50)" "0,71"   "1,28"   "1,77"   "1,60"   "1,87"
```

---

*Data:*

```
x <- '0,60,(0,50),0,71,1,28,1,77,1,60,1,87'
```